# How to stack padding materials to pad an edge

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, geometry, elasticity

This is about how to combine materials of various elastic and deformation properties as a stack to show different properties as a stack.

A cardboard box has two holes punched in the side of the box to lift it by hand.

Lifting the box using two hands in the punched holes is painful, because its content is heavy. The edges of the cardboard press hard against the fingers.

The force per area is to be reduced, to reduce the the pain. To accomplish this, there are the following padding materials available:

- a soft sponge
- a hard sponge
- a thin, but stiff cardboard
- a thicker, but softer cardboard

Each of the materials is available in multiple pieces. (If a solution with the available materials seems impossible, additional materials may be used.)

**How to create a good padding by stacking these materials?**

Comment: I'd just use the additional materials to construct a forklift.  Minimal "pressure per area".

Comment: @Mike I think it's hard to lift a forklift manually. Ok, depends on the forklift.

Comment: The down-votes probably reflect the fact that this is an Engineering-type question (no single solution, vague or unspecified criteria), and that you have not shown effort to solve the problem yourself and to identify a conceptual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, sarcasm aside, I'll try to answer the question since no one else will.  First I should just point out that the downvotes and close votes are presumably because there just aren't enough specifics here to truly answer the question.  Moreover, my comment was meant to point out the utter arbitrariness of a question that allows anything to be used.  Nonetheless, I think I can give some relevant physics-inspired guidance.

The most important point is that pressure is force per unit area (which makes your phrase "pressure per area" redundant).  Now, since the box presumably has some fixed weight, the *force* part of this quantity is fixed — at least to a good approximation.  So if your objective is to minimize the pressure, your objective is really to *maximize* the area over which this force is exerted.

As general guidelines, flexible things will tend to flex so much that they fail to exert any force, and therefore don't increase the area very much, even though any given place where they still contact your hand will feel more comfortable per unit force.  On the other hand, stiff things may provide a larger geometrical area, but will not conform to your hand and thus may actually *decrease* the area over which your hand is making contact, thus increasing the pressure.  So the basic strategy is to use stiff things farther from your hand, and progressively softer things closer to your hand.  Therefore, at a guess as to the relative stiffnesses and softnesses of your materials, I would order them as follows:

1. box
2. stiff cardboard
3. softer cardboard
4. hard sponge
5. soft sponge
6. forklift
7. hand

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the issues leading to down votes. When I saw them, I figured it may be because there was too much fluff around the actual question. But also, I had the tag "condensed matter" initially, which seems not wise in retrospect. (With "optionally", I wanted to express "if necessary" - I edited)

Comment: Experimentally, I see that stiff materials fold near the edge of the previous area, so they increase it only by the thickness of the material, if it is not compressible. Even less if it is compressible, as it will be compressed at the edge. As long as the edge is not padded, at least.